# Probelm After Changing password in ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, login, openldap

I am using ubuntu system which uses  openldap for user login authentication. For changing my login password i used "$sudo passwd"  and changed it. (of course the password given is same as old one). Then onwards when i trying to run "apt" command it showing command not found. and for some other programs it showing segmentation fault. Can any one tell me why I am facing issue and how to solve this.

Comment: Will you be solving it with programming?

Comment: Don't have enough rep to suggest this is moved to serverfault.. can someone else? EDIT: OP, unless you're asking how to debug whatever application is segfaulting..?

Comment: Please post the ouput to: 'echo $PATH'

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is unrelated to you changing password.

You either did something more, or it is just coincidence with some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You changed *which* password?

`sudo passwd` changes root's password, not yours.

And there is no command called apt.  It's `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

Unless you have an alias `alias apt=apt-get`.  Whether that works with sudo will depend on which file you put the alias in.